# hotspot login with facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hotspot

I am developping a hotspot login page that uses FB login. My problem is that when the user clicks the FB login page he should be redirected to the FB page, but at that stage there is internet connexion allowed yet by the hotspot.  I assume FB does use some sort of CDN (content delivery network), such that I could not use a simple list of IP addresses. I could put *.facebook.com into the walled garden. This would allow users to connect to facebook - but this will users also allow to use facebook completely without logging into the hotspot at all (what I probably don´t want)

Or maybe there is there a CDN server that allows only to use the login page and get the user credentials without being able to browse and see facebook content ?
All I want is use only the FB API without the site itself

Comment: you mean using the facebook data without loging from its site but requesting via api?

Comment: yes exactly :) I use the API to redirect the user to the login page then redirect back to my hotspot login interface

Comment: Thats not possibly facebook isnot validating the users from api but from their main site only and redirecting from theirs to urs :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me put my two cents for others even though it might be late for you.

> This would allow users to connect to facebook - but this will users also allow to use facebook completely without logging into the hotspot at all.

Keep in mind that the main use of facebook are users scrolling through their timeline wich consists of posts that usually are links to the internet...

So a user might be able to somewhat use facebook but as soon as the user clicks something that is outside of mikrotik's walled garden the hotspot login page will popup.